# Turning on debug output for python 3 urllib

Tags: python, http, debugging, python-3.x, urllib

In python 2, it was possible to get debug output from urllib by doing

```
import httplib
import urllib
httplib.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1
response = urllib.urlopen('http://example.com').read()
```

However, in python 3 it looks like this has been moved to

```
http.client.HTTPConnection.set_debuglevel(level)
```

However, I'm using urllib not http.client directly. How can I set it up so that my http request display debugging information in this way?

Here's what I"m using so far. What's the best way to proceed if I want to be able to get debug information?

```
#Request Login page
cookiejar = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookiejar))
request = urllib.request.Request(options.uri)
add_std_headers(request)
response = opener.open(request)
response_string = response.read().decode("utf8")
# ...
```

Comment: This is indeed a Python bug. Submitted https://bugs.python.org/issue26892.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You were right the first time. You can simply add the line `http.client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1` at the start of your file to turn on HTTP debugging application-wide. `urllib.request` still uses `http.client`.

It seems that there's also a way to set the debuglevel for a single handler (by creating `urllib.request.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1)` and building an opener with that), but on my installation of Python3 (3.0b3) it's not actually implemented. I imagine that's changed in more recent versions!

Comment: This does not appear to be working anything in Python 3.10.7. Setting `http.client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1` has no affect on subsequent calls to `urllib.request.urlopen`.

Comment: In Python versions 3.5.2 and above the `HTTPConnection.debuglevel` is ignored as a result of [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/9642eedc0a6d90d9502658a6569518741eea9ef3) change. I opened a [PR](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/99353) that should hopefully fix it.

Comment: In Python 3.10 this construct works: 
`build_opener(HTTPCookieProcessor(cookiejar), HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1))`

Answer (score 3):

For those who are seeing this question more recently (since ~May, 2016), while the accepted answer might have been correct at some point, it appears that since Python version 3.5.2 the `http.client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel` is entirely ignored in favor of the `debuglevel` constructor argument for `urllib.request.HTTPHandler`.

This is due to [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/9642eedc0a6d90d9502658a6569518741eea9ef3) change that sets the value of `http.client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel` to whatever is set in `urllib.request.HTTPHandler`'s constructor argument `debuglevel`, on [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.5.2/Lib/urllib/request.py#L1224) line

A [PR](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/99353) has been opened to fix this, but in the mean time you can monkey patch the `__init__` methods of `HTTPHandler` and `HTTPSHandler` to respect the global values like so:

```py
https_old_init = urllib.request.HTTPSHandler.__init__

def https_new_init(self, debuglevel=None, context=None, check_hostname=None):
    debuglevel = debuglevel if debuglevel is not None else http.client.HTTPSConnection.debuglevel
    https_old_init(self, debuglevel, context, check_hostname)

urllib.request.HTTPSHandler.__init__ = https_new_init

http_old_init = urllib.request.HTTPHandler.__init__

def http_new_init(self, debuglevel=None):
    debuglevel = debuglevel if debuglevel is not None else http.client.HTTPSConnection.debuglevel
    http_old_init(self, debuglevel)

urllib.request.HTTPHandler.__init__ = http_new_init
```

Note: I don't recommend setting the `debuglevel` in `HTTPHandler`'s as a method argument default value because the default values for method arguments get evaluated at function definition evaluation time, which, for `HTTPHandler`'s constructor, is when the module `urllib.request` is imported.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is different today than when this was last answered.

My default `urllib3` connections are going thru `PoolManager`.

Turning on `debug level` is somewhat missing, but it does have a nice `logger` usage now.

https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide.html#logging

values go from

- DEBUG
- INFO
- WARNING
- ERROR
- CRITICAL

Here is the line to start sharing the debug info to stdout

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger("urllib3").setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

This will give you output like this:

```
2023-02-01 21:02:24,221 - Resetting dropped connection: localhost
2023-02-01 21:02:24,227 - http://localhost:9000 "GET /web/path HTTP/1.1" 200 100
```

Comment: This is about urllib3 (a third-party library), not urllib2 (included in Python 3).